# Flutter animation on navigating backwards

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

When navigating in Flutter, I use the `PageRouteBuilder` with a nice little animation. I really like the `Curves.elasticOut` but when I push on the 'back'-button on my phone, I'd like the transition to be 'different'. Currently, it just uses the applied animation, just played backwards. It seems unnatural when `Curves.elasticOut` is played backwards, as if the screen needs to hop before it can jump back to the previous screen.

Is there a way to make it possible to use the `Curves.elasticIn` when navigating backwards?

Answer (score 4):

Using the example:

```
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      var begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
      var end = Offset.zero;
      var curve = Curves.elasticIn;
      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));
      print("primary: ${animation}");
      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
```

The parameter `animation` in `transitionBuilder` contains the property `status` which returns an `AnimationStatus`.

A simple

```
var curve = animation.status == AnimationStatus.reverse ? Curves.elasticIn : Curves.elasticOut ;
```

will do.